# Can I use 'weighability' when referring to the trait of something that is able to be weighed?

Tags: word-usage

Or, in another form:

> The deli at the supermarket sells *weighable* products

Or is it

> weight ability

which is what the spell checker keeps correcting to?

Comment: The expression that is commonly used  is "sell something "by the weight", so your sentence would be more naturally expressed as " *the deli ..sell products by the weight" * -

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about weighable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you want is the first one. The adjective, meaning able to be weighed.

**weighable**
[ref](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weighable)

*Additional (courtesy of Max Williams)*

In the UK at least, groceries which are priced by weight like this are referred to as "loose", like "Broccolli (loose) - £1.85 per kg.

Comment: Just as an aside, in the UK at least, groceries which are priced by weight like this are referred to as "loose", like *"Broccolli (loose) - £1.85 per kg"*

Comment: Thanks @MaxWilliams have added your comment to the answer